# Custom from validation in ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django and i start writing my first web application.
https://ibb.co/jDPwSHG
I want to make custom validation, for exemple winner cannot be also lost.
How can i do that using ModelForm ?
Can anybody show me a example of this solution ?

My model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

players = (
    ('Mateuszex', 'Mateuszex'),
    ('Piwkief', 'Piwkief'),
    ('Młody', 'Młody'),
    ('Prezes', 'Prezes'),
    ('Bogusław', 'Bogusław'),

)

winner = ((0, 'Gracz1'), (1, 'Gracz2'))

number_of_sets = ((0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3))



class MatchScore(models.Model):
    winner = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=players, blank=False)
    lost = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=players, blank=False)
    winner_sets = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=number_of_sets, blank=False)
    lost_sets = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=number_of_sets, blank=False)
    duel_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=False, default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.winner + ' ' + str(self.winner_sets) + ' - ' + str(self.lost_sets) + ' ' +  self.lost
```

my froms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import MatchScore, Table


class MatchScoreForm(ModelForm):
    # winner = MatchScore(help_text='Use puns liberally')
    class Meta:
        model = MatchScore
        fields = ['winner', 'winner_sets', 'lost_sets', 'lost', 'duel_date']
```

my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect

from .forms import MatchScoreForm
from .models import MatchScore, Table

from django.contrib import messages


# Create your views here.

def all_scores(request):
    match = MatchScore.objects.order_by('-duel_date')
    return render(request, 'pingpong.html', {'form': match})

def new_score(request):
    form = MatchScoreForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect(all_scores)
    return render(request, 'match_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Can you share the current state of your `ModelForm`? Please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

To add validation to your form, you need to implement various methods. For example to validate some field you need to implement `clean_<field>` method where `<field>` is the name of the field. If you need some validation where you need to access multiple fields you need to override the `clean` method:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MatchScoreForm(ModelForm):
    # winner = MatchScore(help_text='Use puns liberally')
    class Meta:
        model = MatchScore
        fields = ['winner', 'winner_sets', 'lost_sets', 'lost', 'duel_date']
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if cleaned_data.get('winner') == cleaned_data.get('lost'):
            raise ValidationError("The Winner and Loser cannot be the same.")
        return cleaned_data
```

Reference: [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)